# pycrypto is slow encrypting and decrypting

Tags: python-2.7, cryptography, pycrypto

In practice, I select an executable. **Size 20Mb**.

I read the content using `file.read(size=16)`.

If length of the returned byte string is less than 16 I fill the rest with `\0 (NULL)`.

```
f = open("./installer.exe","rb")

obj = AES.new(b"0123456789012345",AES.MODE_CBC, b"\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0")

bs = b""
t = f.read(16)
while t != b"":
    if len(t) < 16:
        t = t + b"\0" * (16 - len(t)) # if < 16 bytes using padding
        bs = bs + obj.encrypt(t)
    else:
        bs = bs + obj.encrypt(t)
    t = f.read(16)
```

then, **bs** contents the byte string of ALL content encrypted with *0123456789012345*

I realise the mechanism of reading file first, then I encrypt the content as seen in the above piece of code (using `obj.encrypt()`). Then I write a new file with the content encrypted. The I read the data of *encrypted file* and by a similar procedure decrypt the data using *obj.decrypt* in intervals of 16 bytes and then I write a new file with the decrypted data.

**This takes approximately 3 minutes**.

¿It's fast, slow, or expected?

According to what I saw, the module is written in C. ¿Maybe should I use Cython embedded to make it faster?

How PGP can supposedly decrypt higher amounts of data in real time, for example, in an encrypted virtual disk?

**edit:**

This take almost same:

```
obj = AES.new(b"0123456789012345",AES.MODE_CBC, b"\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0")

bs = b""
t = f.read(16)
while t != b"":
    if len(t) < 16:
        t = t + b"\0" * (16 - len(t))
        bs = bs + t
    else:
        bs = bs + t
    t = f.read(16)

bse = obj.encrypt(bs)
```

Comment: Maybe decide whether this is slower than what you need or good enough for your needs? Besides your file reading method looks pretty unsafe. Why not just do `with open("fileName.ext", "r") as f: stuff - f.read()`?

Comment: I need to know if there is any performance difference in calling functions of previously compiled modules or using directly C

edit:
what are the performance differences using or not using with? Thanks

Comment: By and large (i.e. for any module) pure C is going to be faster than C wrapped into Python or even Cython/Weave. Check this out (Numpy is also based on C): http://tim.vanwerkhoven.org/post/2011/11/17/Python-meets-C%3A-Cython There are many ways in which you can write Cython, if you do it very well then probably the difference between pure C won't be as large. But certainly Cython/Weave will be faster than C wrappers.

Comment: 1) Why are you working on 16 byte blocks instead of something sane, like a few kilobytes? Just because AES has 16 byte blocks internally doesn't mean you need to call `encrypt` on each 16 byte block individually. 2) Your string concatenation patterns looks dubious. I don't know python, but in C# that'd be an O(n^2) algorithm. Wouldn't some kind of stream be more appropriate?

Comment: Even a mediocre AES implementation in c will encrypt your file in a second. So the problem is most likely in your code (I'm betting on the small blocks).

Comment: Its true. encrypt admits multiples of 16. I'll test it.

Comment: if first I create a byte string reading 16 bytes each time and finally i decrypt or encrypt... takes only a little less.... seconds less...

Comment: The problem is in reading and writing data by 16 byte blocks, not because of AES. Try to read to larger buffer, i.e. 64k or so, and you'll feel the difference.

Comment: I will measure the total length of all (reading all to end) and if it is not a multiple of 16 then will fill the remainder to the nearest multiple. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok. The problem was the size of the buffers encrypted. I decided to use 64000 bytes strings.

The procedure its simple. *total size / string segments* -> encrypt. And in the last segment, if the size of the segment is inferior to 64000 AND NOT multiple of 16, finds the nearest multiple and the remaining space is filled

```
bs = b""
dt = f.read()
dtl = len(dt)
dtr = ( dtl / 64000 ) + 1

for x in range(0, dtr):
    if x == dtr-1:
        i1 = 64000 * x
        dst = dtl - i1
        i = math.ceil(dst / 16.0) * 16
        dst = i - dst
        buf = dt[i1:] + (b"\0" * int(dst))
        bs = bs + obj.encrypt(buf)
    else:
        i1, i2 = 64000 * x ,  64000 * (x+1)
        bs = bs + obj.encrypt(dt[i1:i2])
```

Now takes 10 seconds.
Thanks for all.